# I can't get form submit to work in html / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text, submit

I have tried a bunch of different things as well as searching and googling but I just can't see how to make some very basic code work.Trying to let the user submit text input.

This code below should just change the first paragraph to say working.

```
<HTML>
<CENTER>
<BR>
<H1>Test</H1>
<BR>
<p id="ParaOne"></p>
<BR>
<input type="text" id="TextInput" Value="" onsubmit="Test">

<script>
var CharOne = ["name"]


function Test() {
    document.getElementById("ParaOne").innerHTML = "Working";
}

document.getElementById("ParaOne").innerHTML = "Enter Name:";

</script>

</HTML>
```

Ideally I would able to save whatever they entered into a variable and then display the entered name but as of now I can't get anything to work. not even a basic function to update the paragraph to sy working.

Comment: Ideally you would get a HTML tutorial first as this is not valid markup, nor is there a form to submit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `javascript` methods `onchange` or `onkeydown` to trigger input from the input field, you don't need to submit a form. But in case you needed just that I added the example. I used `jQuery` instead of `plain javascript` to write the functions because now they practically become `one-line` functions.

`onchange` will wait for the user to press enter or for the input element to loose focus to call the function.

`onkeydown` will call the function on every key press.

`e.preventDefault()` cancels the default action of the element, which in this case is a submit action, and lets us make the decision through code whether to submit or not.

Below are some `javascript/jQuery` test functions and a sample `HTML` file so you can test out what works best for you.

**EDIT:** I added some examples on how to store the current value of an input  field into a variable

```js
// get the Value of input element directly into a variable
var myVariable = $('#theInput_1').val();

// myVariable will return empty string since the input element is empty
console.log('This is the starting value of the 1st input element: ' + myVariable);


// Function for onkeydown test
function testKeyDown()
{
  // stored in a variable which is not available outside the function
  var myVariable = $('#theInput_1').val();
  $('#paraOne').text(myVariable);
  
  // test output - $('#theInput_1').val() will return empty
console.log('This is the changed value of the 1st input element: ' + myVariable);
}

// Function for onchange test
function testOnChange()
{
  $('#paraTwo').text($('#theInput_2').val());
}

// Function for submit test
$( "#submit" ).on( "click", function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default action of submit
  $('#paraThree').text($('#theInput_3').val());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="paraOne">This text will be replaced on success.</p>
<input type="text" id="theInput_1" onkeydown="testKeyDown();" size="50" value="" placeholder="onkeydown test" />

<p id="paraTwo">This text will be replaced on success.</p>
<input type="text" id="theInput_2" onchange="testOnChange();" size="50" value="" placeholder="onchange test" />

<p id="paraThree">This text will be replaced on success.</p>
<form>
<input type="text" id="theInput_3" size="50" value="" placeholder="form submit test" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit me" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, very informative. Sadly I think I will have to restart some tutorials as it has been along time since I codded in javascript. I did get the form mostly working before seeing your answer but I still like yours better however I can't figure out how to save the input into a variable now,

I was convinced I could just google each issue as it came up but somehow that doesn't seam to be the case,

Comment: I will edit my answer so variables can get the values of the input fields.

Comment: I edited. I added a `console.log()` so you can track the value of the variable `myVariable` which extracts the value of input field `input_1`. The first line of code in the `Javascript` is how you would extract the value from the input field. I also added an example on how to do this from inside a function, but keep in mind that variables that are declared inside a function get destroyed after the function returns (is finished).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onsubmit` event for the textbox. You can use that event on the form (which I don't see in your question). Although not required, I would also add a submit button, because that's a better design.

Also it's wasteful to assign an initial value to `ParaOne` in JavaScript, simply type the value inside the element.

```
<form onsubmit="Test();">
  <p id="ParaOne">Enter Name:</p>
  <input type="text" id="TextInput">
</form>
<script>
  function Test() {
    document.getElementById("ParaOne").innerHTML = "Working";
  }
</script>
```

Important note: Although the code above is how you should do it, I don't really see the point. The form will be submitted immediately after changing the text of `ParaOne` which will reload the page and you will see the initial value again (and probably think it didn't work). It will work but very fast so nobody will really see it, so what's the point?